# Struct methods insde a class

Tags: c++

I have few classes that use same struct as a private member. 
Is it possible to create struct getter functions which i can use from/in classes?
I feel like creating the funcs. for every class is not the right way to do it.?

Something like this:

```
someheader

struct A {
    A(const int& vl) : someval(vl) {}
    int someval{0};
    int getSomeval() const {return someval;}
};

B
include "someheader.h"
class B {
public:
    B();

private:
    A a;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    int v = b.getSomeval();
}
```

Comment: Off topic but why take a int as a reference in your constructor?

Comment: friend ........

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: As @HolyBlackCat mentions, use private inheritance instead of a private member, then a `using` statement to bring the private base class' member function into public scope:

```
class B : A {
public:
  B(int i) : A(i) {}

  using A::getSomeval; /*
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
};


int main() {
  B b(42);
  std::cout << b.getSomeval() << std::endl;
}
```

---

You could public-inherit the structs:

```
class B : public A {
public:
  B(int i) : A(i) {}
};

B b(42);
b.getSomeval();
```

Or make `A` a public data member of `B`:

```
class B {
public:
  B(int i) : a(i) {}
  A a;
};

B b(42);
b.a.getSomeval();
```

However this method breaks encapsulation.

Most IDEs will auto-construct getter and setter functions for you - you don't necessarily need to write them out by hand.

Comment: As an alternative to public inheritance one could use private inheritance and make the getter public using `public:` `using A::getSomeval;`.

Comment: I did not know this was a thing. Thanks!